# How to determine what method is being used?

Tags: time-series, modeling, forecasting

I was wondering what time series model would forecast future values in such a  static but decreasing manner? ( I'm talking about the values around where the circle appears, as apparently, the data set that I have does that, judging from the graph, but I'm a beginner and not sure what model would do that? though I think it should be a simple one). I just need reasonable ideas :)

Thanks!

[image: data]

Comment: the y axis shows the size of some population at a given point in time, if that is of any help

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more? I still do not understand what's the problem...

Comment: Post your actual historical data and the future values and I will try and reverse engineer the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have available the data set of the predicted values (and not just the graph), then you could apply "reverse-engineering" by trial-and-error, i.e. try to "estimate" a function from this data, treating them as random although they are not, by applying standard time-series approaches. In principle you would eventually find the *exact* forecasting equation.

But generally speaking, the fact that for a specific interval (the circled values) the forecasting function appears to behave as a "~linear function with structural shifts" can not, on its own, help "guess" the function, because, in other parts of the graph the function exhibits different behavior.